# NotifyIcon ContextMenu and too many click events

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wcf

I'm using the `NotifyIcon` class to display an icon in the task tray. The icon performs 2 functions - when the user single-clicks with the left button it should display a window, when the user single-clicks with the right button it should display the context menu. This works fine apart from the window being displayed after the user clicks an option in the context menu. Here's my code:

```
contextMenuItems = new List<MenuItem>();
contextMenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Function A", new EventHandler(a_Clicked)));
contextMenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("-"));
contextMenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Function B", new EventHandler(b_Clicked)));
trayIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
trayIcon.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(trayIcon_IconClicked);
trayIcon.Icon = new Icon(GetType(), "Icon.ico");
trayIcon.ContextMenu = contextMenu;
trayIcon.Visible = true;
```

The problem is that my `trayIcon_IconClicked` event is fired when the user selects "Function A" or "Function B". Why would that be happening?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 3):

By assigning the context menu to the NotifyIcon control, it automatically catches the right-click and opens the assigned context menu there. If you want to perform some logic before actually showing the context menu, then assign a delegate to the contextMenu.Popup event.

```
...
contextMenu.Popup += new EventHandler(contextMenu_Popup);
...

private void trayIcon_IconClicked(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        //Do something here.
    }
    /* Only do this if you're not setting the trayIcon.ContextMenu property, 
    otherwise use the contextMenu.Popup event.
    else if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        //Show uses assigned controls Client location to set position, 
        //so must go from screen to client coords.
        contextMenu.Show(this, this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
    }
    */
}

private void contextMenu_Popup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do something before showing the context menu.
}
```

My guess as to why the window is popping up is that the context menu that you're opening up is using the NotifyIcon as the target control, so when you click on it it's running the click handler you assigned to the NotifyIcon.

*Edit:* Another option to consider is to use ContextMenuStrip instead. The NotifyIcon has a ContextMenuStrip property as well, and it seems to have a lot more functionality associated with it (noticed I could do more, programmable wise). Might want to give that a shot if things aren't working right for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to stop it using the NotifyIcon as the target control? Or perhaps even popup the menu manually? I've tried ContextMenu.Show() but that requires a control as a parameter and does not seem to fire the Popup event.

Comment: Are you handling the right-click within the click-handler of the trayIcon_IconClicked event? If so, don't. Setting the ContextMenu property automatically handles the right-click event of whatever control is assigned the context menu, so you shouldn't need to handle it anymore. That's why it was ommitted in the trayIcon_IconClicked event, because you'd just be duplicating events. Try it and let me know.

Comment: I wasn't handling the click manually, I was setting the ContextMenu property but that gives the behaviour of firing the trayIcon_IconClicked event when the user selects an item from the context menu. The above example doesn't work as "this" is an Application object. I'm going to try the ContextMenuStrip and see if that gives better results.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. 
Changing the NotifyIcon's ContextMenu to ContextMenuStrip does not solved the problem (in fact when I changed the ContextMenu the Click event happens when the ContextMenuStrip showed instead of when the user actualy clicked on one of the items.

My solution to the problem is to change the event I used to show the left click contextmenu. Instead of using the Click eventhandler I use the MouseUp and check which MouseButton clicked.

Building the NotifyIcon (notifyContext is a System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip)

```
m_notifyIcon.MouseUp += new Forms.MouseEventHandler(m_notifyIcon_MouseUp);
m_notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip = notifyContext;

Handling the left click event and show the main contextmenu:

        void m_notifyIcon_MouseUp(object sender, Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                mainContext.IsOpen = ! mainContext.IsOpen;
            }
        }
```