# How can I prevent a click on MenuItem from being handled in the parent control?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `NotifyIcon` with a `ContextMenu`.

```
myNotifyIcon = new NotifyIcon(new Container());
myNotifyIcon.Click += new EventHandler(myNotifyIcon_Click);
MenuItem entQuit = new MenuItem("Menu Item Text");
entQuit.Click += new EventHandler(entQuit_Click);
myNotifyIcon.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
myNotifyIcon.ContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(entQuit);
```

When I click on a `MenuItem` within the menu, `myNotifyIcon.Click` fires, causing `myNotifyIcon_Click()` to run (which I don't want). How can I prevent this behavior?

<s>I already looked at the answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797661/notifyicon-contextmenu-and-too-many-click-events) but they don't seem to actually address the issue. To be clear, the issue is when I left-click an item *within* the context menu, *not* with the right-click that opens the menu to begin with.</s>

## Edit

I was mistaken about the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797661/notifyicon-contextmenu-and-too-many-click-events) not working. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15753187/3938807) seems like it does actually work, though I don't have a clue why.

Comment: I am marking my own Answer as accepted for lack of a better solution. If anyone can explain _why_ my solution is working the way it does, I'd be happy if you could let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it looks like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15753187/3938807) may actually help after all. I was able to solve the problem by handling `NotifyIcon.MouseClick` instead of `NotifyIcon.Click`, and checking the `MouseEventArgs.Button` property

In the end, this seems to work:

```
myNotifyIcon = new NotifyIcon(new Container());
myNotifyIcon.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(myNotifyIcon_Click);
MenuItem entQuit = new MenuItem("Menu Item Text");
entQuit.Click += new EventHandler(entQuit_Click);
myNotifyIcon.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
myNotifyIcon.ContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(entQuit);
```

`myNotifyIcon_Click` looks like this:

```
void myNotifyIcon_Click(object source, MouseEventArgs e)
{
 if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) //For some reason this is necessary.
    { //Do stuff here }
}
```

I can't say I understand *why* this solves the problem, or why I need to check `if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)` when the click causing the whole issue *is* a left click, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you should consider using the newer ContextMenuStrip.

However, if that's not possible, then a solution is to determine if a menu item was clicked by looking at the position of the mouse.  This solution uses the GetMenuItemRect to determine if a menu item was clicked on.

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Form2 : Form {
    NotifyIcon myNotifyIcon = new NotifyIcon() { Icon = SystemIcons.Exclamation };
    MenuItem entQuit = new MenuItem("Menu Item Text");
    MenuItem entQuit2 = new MenuItem("Menu Item Text2");
    List<Rectangle> rectangles = new List<Rectangle>();

    public Form2() {
        //ContextMenuStrip cms;
        myNotifyIcon.Click += myNotifyIcon_Click;
        entQuit.Click += entQuit_Click;

        var cm = new ContextMenu();
        myNotifyIcon.ContextMenu = cm;
        myNotifyIcon.ContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(entQuit);
        myNotifyIcon.ContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(entQuit2);
        myNotifyIcon.Visible = true;

        myNotifyIcon.ContextMenu.Popup += delegate {
            this.BeginInvoke((Action) delegate {
                var h = myNotifyIcon.ContextMenu.Handle;
                rectangles = new List<Rectangle>();

                for (int i = 0; i < cm.MenuItems.Count; i++) {
                    RECT cr = new RECT();
                    GetMenuItemRect(IntPtr.Zero, h, (uint) i, ref cr);
                    rectangles.Add(new Rectangle(cr.Left, cr.Top, cr.Right - cr.Left, cr.Bottom - cr.Top));
                }
            });
        };
    }

    void entQuit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    }

    void myNotifyIcon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        bool OnMenuItem = false;
        var mp = Form.MousePosition;
        foreach (var r in rectangles) {
            if (r.Contains(mp)) {
                OnMenuItem = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // reset rectangles to prevent icon click from scanning previous rectangles
        rectangles = new List<Rectangle>();

        if (OnMenuItem) { // detect if click was on a menu item
            return;
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetMenuItemRect(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hMenu, uint uItem, ref RECT rect);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
    }
}
```